# What are vectorized environments in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what and when vectorized environments should be used. If you can provide an example of a use case, that would be great.

Documentation of vectorized environments in SB3:
https://stable-baselines3.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/vec_envs.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vectorized Environments are a method for stacking multiple independent environments into a single environment. Instead of executing and training an agent on 1 environment per step, it allows to train the agent on multiple environments per step.

Usually you also want these environment to have different seeds, in order to gain more diverse experience. This is very useful to speed up training.

I think they are called "vectorized" since each training step the agent observes multiple states (inserted in a vector), outputs multiple actions (one for each environment), which are inserted in a vector, and receives multiple rewards. Hence the "vectorized" term

Comment: Hello. Even though I've read the docs for SB3 and Gym, I still don't understand what's the benefit of Vectorized Environments, and what problem does it solve? Is there any specific use case?

Comment: It basically allows to train an agent on multiple environment in parallel. Since most of the reinforcement learning algorithm are very "experience" hungry, then having multiple environments trained in parallel makes the agent learn quickly how to behave. Moreover, since most of the times the environment are not that computationally expensive to run, having the possibility to run multiple copies of them simultaneously becomes simple even in simple laptops.